# problem with if statement? not equal rule doesnt work?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 1000 dataframes that have same structure, but some of them may contain strings as values. With all those frames I need to do the same calculations, just exclude rows in those dataframes where subsrings occur. The example of the structure of the dataset with string is as follows:

```
time    x           y               z
0.00  run_failed  run_failed   run_failed
0.02  run_failed  run_failed   run_failed
0.03  test_failed test_failed  test_failed
0.04  44            321         644
0.04  44            321         644
0.04  44            321         644
0.03  test_failed test_failed  test_failed
0.04  44            321         644
0.04  44            321         644
```

If too look at df.dtypes method, those dfs that contain substring will always be object type, while "normal" dfs - of float64

So in order to deal with it I made the following script:

```
for df in dfs:  
   add = 0
   z = pd.read_csv(df)
   if type(z["x"]) != np.float64:
        bmb = z[z['x'].str.contains('failed')]
        z = z.drop(bmb.index)
        add = len(bmb)
        print(add)
   ....
   and then the code for doing calculations assuming that if string occured, it was dropped inside if statement
```

But when I run code it returns error: "Can only use .str accessor with string values!" pointing inside if statement block, however the dataset if fully of float64 type and why it tried to process this " bmb = z[z['x'].str.contains('failed')]" command is not clear for me at all.

Comment: what should the `z["x"]` mean? or is that how you access values with dataframes? cause it won't work in a `list`.

Comment: @cyberghost z["x"] is how I refer to column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if type(z["x"]) != np.float64:
```

Here you are getting type of *column of DataFrame* which is `Series` consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3]},dtype="int32")
print(type(df["x"]))
```

gives output

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Therefore your condition always holds (i.e. it is same as writing `if True:`). If you are interested in type of hold values use `.dtype` attribute

```
print(df["x"].dtype)
```

gives output

```
int32
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured the problem.
First, I changed

```
if type(z["x"]) != np.float64
```

to

```
z['x'].dtype == 'object'
```

and in further calculations, when I get pandas column as series, I added .astype(float) as seems like if dataframe was processed through if statement, values in the column become string, as they were returned as follows:

```
array(['0.00260045', '0.00257398', '0.00247482', ..., '0.02017634', '0.01997158','0.02019846'])
```

Comment: This is what the other answer explained, you might want to consider accepting it